# What character encoding is Revit using in the type catalogue?

Tags: revit-api

I am currently working with a project that involves Revit.

Revit can export a text file which includes the paramters called a type catalogue.

The photometric file in the Revit model is represented by a long string of character and appears in the text file as follows:

```
䕉乓㩁䵌㘭ⴳ〲㈰਍呛卅嵔嘠剆㈭〰㈹ⴵ㠰㈸䴭൓嬊䕔呓䅌嵂䔠敮杲汹湩൥嬊卉啓䑅呁嵅㔠㔯㈯㈰റ嬊䅍啎䅆嵃䔠敮杲汹湩൥嬊啌䥍䅎剉嵅䔠敮杲汹湩⁥㔶㈠〹〰浭਍䱛䵕䅃嵔嘠獩⁯慌卢楰湯ⴠ猠牥慩㩬ㄠㄳ㔴㈰㘲″敳獮牯猠牥慩㩬㌠㈰㠸〳㔵ര嬊䅌偍⁝਍佛䡔剅⁝਍䥔呌丽乏൅ㄊⴠ‱‱㜳㌠‷‱′⸰㘰‵㠲㤮㠸〠〮਍‱‱ㄸ⸳㠰ഴ《〮㔠〮ㄠ⸰‰㔱〮㈠⸰‰㔲〮㌠⸰‰㔳〮㐠⸰‰㔴〮㔠⸰‰㔵〮㘠⸰‰㔶〮㜠⸰‰㔷〮㠠⸰‰㔸〮㤠⸰‰㔹〮਍ㄠ〰〮ㄠ㔰〮ㄠ〱〮ㄠ㔱〮ㄠ〲〮ㄠ㔲〮ㄠ〳〮ㄠ㔳〮ㄠ〴〮ㄠ㔴〮ㄠ〵〮ㄠ㔵〮ㄠ〶〮ㄠ㔶〮ㄠ〷〮ㄠ㔷〮਍ㄠ〸〮਍⸰‰〱〮㈠⸰‰〳〮㐠⸰‰〵〮㘠⸰‰〷〮㠠⸰‰〹〮ㄠ〰〮ㄠ〱〮ㄠ〲〮ㄠ〳〮ㄠ〴〮ㄠ〵〮ㄠ〶〮ㄠ〷〮ㄠ〸〮ㄠ〹〮㈠〰〮㈠〱〮㈠〲〮㈠〳〮㈠〴〮㈠〵〮㈠〶〮㈠〷〮㈠〸〮㈠〹〮㌠〰〮㌠〱〮㌠〲〮㌠〳〮㌠〴〮㌠〵〮㌠〶〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㜸⸶㘰‷〳㜴⸲㤴‹㤲㌷⸲㠴‸㠲㜷⸹㠴′㜲㐵⸸㈷‴㘲〱⸰ㄶ‶㐲㠳⸳㜲‱㈲㠴⸹㘲‷〲㜳⸱㌱റ 㜱㌹⸶㘸‸㔱〷⸵㈰‹㌱㌲⸹ㄳ‴〱㈴⸵㔸‴㜷㤹㐮㔸㔠㌱⸷ㄹ′㘲㔴㔮‶㘶⸹㘵‶⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㠰㈸㐮㐲㌠㐰ㄶ〮㜵㈠㜹㌶㔮㌸㈠㜸〹㜮㜶㈠㔷㠶㠮‹㘲ㄱ⸳㌳‷㐲㈴⸱〷‶㈲ㄵ⸲〳‷〲㤳⸲㜰ള 㠱㐰⸰㈶‷㔱㐷⸰㤷‱㌱㜲⸲㔳‹〱㈵⸴㜱‱㠷㔵㜮㤱㔠㔱⸲㌶‶㘲㔲〮㤸㘠㔵ㄮ㜴〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㠸⸸㐸‱〳㐴⸹ㄶ‵㤲㤷⸴㜶‷㠲〸⸲㘰‱㜲㠵⸹㔰‷㘲㈱⸶㄰‶㐲㘴⸰㐱‱㈲㌵⸵㐳‷〲ㄴ⸲㔹ള 㠱㐱⸴㜳‷㔱㜷⸶ㄶ″㌱〳⸵㔴‶〱㈶⸲㜴‹㤷ㄱ㤮ㄶ㔠㘱⸷㘳‱㘲㐰㘮㠱㘠〴㜮㜲〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳ㄸ⸷㔰‶〳㌴⸲㄰‷㤲㈷⸵ㄷ‴㠲㔷⸹㌹‴㜲㜵⸰㌵‶㘲㈱⸸㜰‱㐲㔴⸲㠰‶㈲㐵⸷㔴‹〲㌴⸵ㄲസ 㠱〲⸴㈷ㄠ㠵㤴〮㠰ㄠ㌳㘵㐮㐰ㄠ㜰㤰㔮㔵㠠㄰⸹㘸‵㈵㔶㠮㐳㈠㌷⸲㠶‸㠶⸱㈸‷⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㜰㤱㈮㄰㌠㐰㈱㌮㐶㈠㘹㌲㐮㈠㜸〰〮㈵㈠㔷㤳ㄮ㠲㈠ㄶ㘲㔮㈸㈠㐴㠲㔮㔸㈠㔲㔵㤮㌲㈠㐰㜵㤮㐵਍ㄠ㈸〵㔮㤳ㄠ㤵㌳㘮㤱ㄠ㐳㌱㌮㠰ㄠ㜰㈹㠮㐳㠠㐱⸴㘹‶㌵㈹ㄮ㌶㈠ㄹ⸰㜲‸㐷⸱㐴‷⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㘷㌮㜰㌠㌰㔶㐮㌱㈠㔹㤶㌮‷㠲㔶⸱〳‷㜲〵⸰㤵‷㘲〱⸹㐴‵㐲㈴⸳㔵′㈲㐵⸹㐰‴〲㤴⸳㔳ഹ 㠱㤲⸸ㄷ‸㔱㠹⸱㔷‴㌱㜴⸴㜶‹〱㜸⸰㠸㠠㔲⸵㈰‹㔵〰㜮‹〳㈵㠮ㄲ㠠ㄵ㜮㈷〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㠶⸸㘳‷〳㤲⸱㘱‴㤲㘵⸳㜵‱㠲ㄶ⸳㐷″㜲㔴⸴㈹‶㘲㜰⸶㔶′㐲㌴⸷㐰‸㈲㈵⸶㌸‱〲㐵⸱㌳ഷ 㠱㐳⸹㘳‱㔱㤹⸳㤳‶㌱㐵⸰〵‸〱㐹⸳㠵‸㌸〵ㄮ㜰㔠㤵⸱㔷‸ㄳ〶㌮㘱ㄠ㄰⸲㌸‵⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㤸㘮㜴㌠㈰㔳㐮㔴㈠㔹㤵ㄮ㐰㈠㔸㤷㐮㠱㈠㐷㠱㘮‵㘲㐰⸹〱′㐲㐴⸴㈰″㈲ㄵ⸹㐶‷〲㠵⸳㘳਍ㄠ㌸㜸〮㐷ㄠ〶㌲㔮㐲ㄠ㘳㄰㐮㤶ㄠ〱㤰㘮㠷㠠㌴⸱㈰‶㘵ㄸ㐮㐵㌠㜲⸰㐹‵ㄱ㘶㘮㤱〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㔶⸸㔵″〳㌲⸵㐳㈠㔹㠵㜮㤹㈠㔸㐵㘮㤸㈠㐷〱㐮ㄹ㈠〶㜳㈮㐹㈠㐴ㄳ㐮㠵㈠㔲㜵㜮㜱㈠㘰㜰㘮സ 㠱㠳⸵㔹ㄠㄶ㤰〮㘰ㄠ㘳㜴㜮‵ㄱ㔰⸵㔹‸㐸㤶㐮ㄶ㔠㘷⸷〵′㌳ㄹㄮ㠱ㄠ㤲⸸㐶″⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㜲㐮㘰㌠㈰㔳㈮㘳㈠㔹㠵㐮㐹㈠㔸㤲㤮‵㜲〴⸲㌳′㘲㈰⸵㐴″㐲ㄴ⸸㌹‷㈲㤵⸵㐷″〲㌶⸱㐹സ 㠱㠳⸴㜸‱㘱㤱⸴㐵‱㌱㤶⸴㌰ㄠㄱ㈰㈮㠴㠠〵⸷㠸‸㠵㌵㐮㠹㌠ㄵ⸱㌲‸㐱〳㘮㜶〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㌶⸷㈶㌠㈰㠱㔮㠰㈠㐹㜸㜮㠲㈠㔸㌲〮㠲㈠㐷〲㠮㌵㈠〶㐶㔮㌹㈠㐴㜲㘮㈶㈠㔲㐶㔮㘹㈠㘰㘱ㄮ㐴਍ㄠ㐸㜰㌮㔴ㄠ〶㘹〮㌲ㄠ㘳㔱㐮㜲ㄠ〱㤴㈮㠸㠠㠴⸴㤶‹㠵㠵㤮‴㐳ㄴ㤮‷㌱㔶㐮㤹㠠⸷㠲‴⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㜴㜮㈸㌠㈰㄰㜮ㄸ㈠㐹㜱〮㌲㈠㔸㘱ㄮ㤴㈠㐷㤳㐮㔳㈠ㄶ㌰㜮㈴㈠㐴㘳㌮㠷㈠㔲㌳㔮㄰㈠㘰〰㌮ഴ 㠱㈴⸹ㄸ‹㔱㤹⸷㔵‹㌱㌵⸶㘸‸〱㤹⸶㌳‸㐸ㄶ㔮㔵㔠㘸⸴㠳′㌳㈷㜮㄰ㄠ〳⸰㌳′㜱⸴㘵〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㠶⸰㈷′〳ㄲ⸹㈰′㤲㘴⸸㔸㈠㔸㘷㐮‴㜲㜴⸴㈳‶㘲㤰⸹㠲″㐲〴⸲㔰″㈲㠴⸸㐶‹〲㘵⸷〶സ 㠱㤳⸸㌹″㔱㔹⸹㤷‴㌱〵⸱ㄷ‶〱ㄹ⸷ㄲ′㌸〶㤮㌸㔠㔷⸸㘳‸㈳㐲㜮㤶ㄠ㔱⸰㤰′㤱⸱〶‱⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㜰ㄲ㈮㐰㌠㈰㜴㔮㠴㈠㔹ㄶ㔮㠶㈠㘸㤵ㄮ㄰㈠㔷㐱㜮㌰㈠〶〸㈮㈹㈠㌴㌵㐮㈱㈠㐲㤳㈮㈴㈠㔰㤲ㄮ㌷਍ㄠ㌸〵㈮㈳ㄠ㤵㈴㈮㈹ㄠ㐳ㄸ〮㐴ㄠ㠰㤲㌮㠱㠠㌲⸴㔶‴㘵㔱㈮㤵㌠㔰⸰ㄶ‸㜹⸱㈵‷㠱⸵㠱″⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㜰㈳〮㘳㌠㈰㐶㜮㤸㈠㘹㜰〮㈸㈠㘸〸㠮㤰㈠㔷〱㜮㘰㈠〶㌴㌮㌰㈠㌴㈳㈮‷㈲〴⸸㔲′〲㘴⸱㤵ഴ 㠱㜲⸸㤱‵㔱㤸⸷㤱‵㌱〴⸸㌵‶〱㌷⸸㐲‶ㄸㄱㄮ㐵㔠㜴⸰ㄶ‸㤲㜰〮㠴㠠㠵ㄮ㠲㈠㄰〮㈹〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳ㄷ⸳㤰‷〳㜲⸰㤷‷㤲〶⸵㌴‶㠲㐶⸱〵″㜲㘴⸲㘲‶㔲㠹⸸㐲‵㐲㌳⸸㌶‶㈲㤳⸵㌷㈠㌰㐶㠮㜲਍ㄠㄸ㈸㠮㌰ㄠ㠵㐲㔮㌸ㄠ㈳㐸ㄮ㔰ㄠ㘰㌴㤮㔳㜠㤹⸰ㄴ‶㌵㐲㐮㜲㈠㤷⸴〰‷〸⸹㐸‵㌲⸹ㄲ‴⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㜰㔰㔮㐰㌠㈰ㄹ㘮㘲㈠㘹㘱㐮㤶㈠㘸㈲㜮ㄲ㈠㐷㔴㤮㠴㈠㤵〷ㄮ㌳㈠㌴ㄶ〮㠵㈠㐲㜰㐮㔲㈠㈰㜹㜮ㄶ਍ㄠㄸ㠱ㄮ㘰ㄠ㜵㔶〮㔱ㄠㄳ㔷〮‷〱㘵⸷㌹‵㠷㈹㈮㌰㔠ㄲ⸸㘲‵㘲㜹㔮㜹㜠㈷㘮㤹㈠ㄶ㈮㘲〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㌷⸱㜸‹〳㔳⸶㐸‵㤲㘶⸵㌶′㠲㘶⸵ㄵ‸㜲㈵⸶㐰‹㘲㘰⸳〰‸㐲㌴⸱〶‶㈲㤴⸱㠸‸〲ㄳ⸹㘶ഹ 㠱㐱⸵〷‹㔱㐷⸴㤵‶㌱ㄱ⸲㘱‶〱㐵⸶㤸‸㠷ㄶ㐮㘶㔠㌲⸲㜲‵㘲ㄵ〮㔵㜠㠶㘮㌹㈠㐳㘮ㄵ〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㔷⸸〲′〳㈴⸲〱‸㤲ㄷ⸴㠷‶㠲〷⸸㘲″㜲〶⸶㐱‱㘲㔱⸵㜸‴㐲〵⸲ㄲ‶㈲㜵⸶㤲㈠㌰ㄴ㔮㜷਍ㄠㄸ㌷㌮㈱ㄠ㜵㐲㈮′㌱㐰⸹〳‶〱㈵⸵ㄹ″㠷〳㘮㔸㔠㐲⸶㌲‴㘲㐰㐮ㄶ㜠㐶㜮㤴㈠㠰ㄮ㤱〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳〸⸰㤹‱〳㔴⸴㐶㈠㜹㐳㌮㘸㈠㜸㘳㜮㤸㈠㔷㐹㔮㌴㈠ㄶ㠲㤮㐹㈠㐴㘷㤮㈷㈠㔲〶㘮㌴㈠㌰㔶㈮㠸਍ㄠㄸ㌸〮㔶ㄠ㜵㐳㜮ㄹㄠㄳ㈵㜮ㄠ㔰㘹㌮㘶㜠㌹⸵㘶″㈵ㄹ㔮ㄹ㈠㔶⸸㤴‱ㄸ⸳㠱㈠㌵〮㔱〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㐸⸳㠷‸〳㠴⸷㜱‱㤲㔷⸳㠹‷㠲㘷⸵㘲″㜲㠵⸲㔹″㘲〱⸲〱‵㐲㔴⸱㘶‸㈲㐵⸴㤹‵〲㠳⸸㤹਍ㄠㄸ㈹㠮㠰ㄠ㜵㔴㌮㈶ㄠ㈳㘵〮ㄴㄠ㘰㘶㠮㠱㠠㐰⸰㐶‹㌵㜳〮㄰㈠ㄷ⸲㈵‱㘸⸱㘵‸㤲⸷㔸‹⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㠰㤳㠮㔳㌠㐰㐶㐮㘹㈠㘹㜸㌮㌸㈠㜸ㄳ㌮㜴㈠㔷㤱ㄮ㠱㈠〶㘸㔮㌵㈠㐴〳㔮㜸㈠㔲㌲㘮㐴㈠㐰㠲㐮਍ㄠ㈸〴ㄮ㤶ㄠ㠵〲㤮㌴ㄠ㌳㠷㐮㜱ㄠ㜰㔶㠮㤴㠠〱⸹㘷‱㐵㈴㤮ㄱ㈠㘸⸷㠳‵ㄹ⸶〰‷㤲⸵〶‴⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㠰〲㌮ㄹ㌠㐰㌲㐮㤴㈠㔹㈹〮㘹㈠㘸㘷㘮㌰㈠㐷㜳㠮㐹㈠〶㐷㠮㘰㈠㐴〱㤮㐳㈠㔲〰㐮㐰㈠㐰㌷〮㠸਍ㄠ㈸㤹㤮㠹ㄠ㤵㠱ㄮ㠲ㄠ㔳㜰ㄮ㠵ㄠ㠰㐷㌮ㄷ㠠㘱⸶㈹‶㔵㠶㤮㤷㌠㔰⸵㔸‱㜹⸲〴‶㜲⸷㤵‶⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㜰〵㈮㔹㌠㌰㜶㐮㘱㈠㔹㠴㐮‸㠲㔶⸰㌵′㜲㤳⸶㈲‸㘲㘰⸹㜷‴㐲〴⸶㘳″㈲㠴⸴㔹‷〲ㄵ⸹㜴ള 㠱㘳⸴〸‹㘱〰⸴㐹″㌱ㄶ⸸㤱‶〱㘹⸴㈳㠠㘲⸴㘴‸㜵㐱㘮㤹㌠㌲⸷㠳‶〱〸〮㔰㈠㠳㔮㌴〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㈶⸹㜶㌠㈰㘹㌮㔴㈠㔹㘵㔮㜸㈠㘸㌵ㄮ㌵㈠㌷㐹㈮㘲㈠〶ㄷ㌮㜶㈠㐴㘱㤮㘸㈠㐲㜷㌮㐶㈠㔰㜶㔮㘵਍ㄠ㐸㐳㔮ㄹㄠ〶ㄸ㐮㌰ㄠ㜳ㄱ㔮㈳ㄠ〱㔳㔮ㄹ㠠〴⸲㐳″㠵〸〮㤲㌠ㄴ⸱㤹‸㈱㠳㠮㌱ㄠ㠷㐮ㄶ〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㌵⸶㈱‵〳㐲⸱㐵‹㤲㔵⸳㜸㈠㘸㔴㤮‷㜲㠳⸹㤲‷㘲㘰⸳㜸‹㐲ㄴ⸹〵″㈲㜴⸷㔲‹〲〶⸷㌹ല 㠱㠴⸳㔹‴㘱㌱⸹㈱‶㌱㜷⸴㜰‹ㄱ〱⸲㤳‶㔸ㄲㄮ㐸㘠〰⸵㠳″㔳㈵㐮㈴ㄠ㠳⸶㈳‸㐱⸳〱‸⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㔰㐲ㄮ㜱㌠㈰㔳㘮㜹㈠㔹㠱㔮‷㠲〶⸹㈱‸㜲㜳⸵〸‹㘲㈰⸹㌱‵㐲㤳⸷㐸‷㈲㤴⸹㌵″〲㈶⸵㜱ള 㠱㜴⸱㤹‸㘱㐱⸰ㄸ‵㌱㐷⸴㜲″ㄱ㔱⸵㘸‹㔸㈸㠮㤵㘠㄰⸰㜷″㔳〹㌮ㄱㄠ〵⸰㤰′㠱⸲㐰‹⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㔰㈱ㄮ㤰㌠㈰㤲㜮㌹㈠㐹㌸㈮‷㠲㜵⸲㠲‶㜲㘳⸲㘲㈠㤵㐹㐮㌵㈠㌴㘷ㄮ㤳㈠㔲ㄲ㠮‵〲㐶⸲ㄴഴ 㠱㘴⸰㐰″㘱㐱⸲㘴‱㌱ㄷ⸴㔴‸ㄱ〲⸹㠲‱㘸㐴㔮㔳㘠㄰⸶㔱‴㘳㠲ㄮㄸㄠㄶ⸳㐸‷㈲⸰㤹‷⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㔰㤴㜮㠷㌠㄰㤹㈮㈱㈠㐹㜶㔮‷㠲㘵⸷㘶″㜲㐳⸳㌳㈠㤵ㄷ㘮㈲㈠㌴㌳㠮㐶㈠㔲㠱㘮㈷㈠㔰〶㐮㐲਍ㄠ㌸㈹㠮㌷ㄠ〶㜳〮㈱ㄠ㘳ㄵ㈮㐹ㄠㄱ㈳㘮㈷㠠㜵⸷〲‸㤵㌵㤮㔶㌠㘴⸷㜷‹㐱㔷㠮㠶ㄠ㈲㜮㔸〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㠵⸷㌴‸〳㘱⸸㜵‹㤲㔴⸱㘸′㠲㘵⸳㐰‸㜲㈳⸴㤳‱㔲㐹⸸㌷㈠㈴ㄹ㘮㈳㈠㔲㔱㐮㔸㈠㐰㠷㐮㔲਍ㄠ㌸㔲㜮㈱ㄠ㤵ㄳ㘮㔲ㄠ㔳㠸ㄮㄸㄠ〱㘵〮㌶㠠〵⸹㐹″㠵ㄹ㠮㠲㌠〳⸷㜳‷㌱㜳㠮㜹㈠⸴㠵‱⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㈲㔮㈸㌠㄰〵㌮㌶㈠㐹㠹㠮㌱㈠㔸㘸㜮㘰㈠㌷㈲㤮㐵㈠㤵㔶㌮㤰㈠㌴〰㠮㤱㈠㐲㜵㘮㘰㈠㌰㌹㤮㤱਍ㄠ㈸㐷ㄮ㜳ㄠ㤵㄰㘮㄰ㄠ㐳ㄵ㤮ㄠ㤰ㄵ㠮ㄵ㠠〴⸰㐶‵㜵㜸㌮㈱㌠ㄲ⸴㔴ㄠ㜱⸲㜹‶⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㘵㤮㘱㌠㄰㘳㈮㜵㈠㔹㘶㘮㜹㈠㘸㤱㜮ㄵ㈠㌷㜲㌮㤶㈠㤵㐹㤮㜶㈠㌴㜲ㄮ㈴㈠㌲ㄸ㐮㜶㈠㌰㠰㐮സ 㠱㈲⸷‷㔱㤸⸶㌷‴㌱㤲⸱㌲‷〱㌸⸸‴㈸㜷㌮㜴㔠㘶⸸㈶‸ㄳ㐴〮‵㤹⸹㌰‴⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㘰㔶㐮㈳㌠㄰㠶㌮㜲㈠㘹㌱〮㈸㈠㘸㈵ㄮ㠷㈠㌷〷㜮㐲㈠〶㈰㠮㔶㈠㌴㌳㐮㔵㈠㌲㐵〮㔶㈠㈰㠹㔮㜲਍ㄠㄸ㔶㔮‱㔱㜸⸱㤷‶㌱ㄲ⸴㜲‱〱㘷⸸㘴‱ㄸ㘷㔮㈲㔠㐵⸵㈲‴〳㔵〮㘷㠠㌹㜮㐹〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㐶⸸㤱‱〳㐲⸶㈵‱㤲㌶⸷㘹‸㠲㠶⸳㠹‷㜲㔴⸳㠰㈠㤵㠸㤮㤵㈠㌴㤱㜮㤴㈠㌲㔷㌮㔵㈠㌰㐶〮㈵਍ㄠ〸㜸㔮㤶ㄠ㠵㘲㜮㌴ㄠ㈳ㄲ〮㔴ㄠ㜰㈴ㄮ㤳㠠㤰⸸㈲‴㐵㜱〮㤴㈠㐹⸷㠵′㔸⸷ㄳ〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㘶⸱㤹′〳㈳⸳㐷‸㤲㘶⸵㄰″㠲ㄷ⸵〸‴㜲ㄵ⸸㔵′㔲㤹⸲㤰‴㐲ㄳ⸷〷″㈲〴⸲㐲‴〲〴⸸㌵സ 㠱㄰⸸ㄸ‴㔱㠷⸳㌲‱㌱㈲⸷ㄶ‱〱㠶⸹㐴‹〸㈱㜮㔸㔠〳⸰㈶‱㠲㈴㌮㐹㠠㈱ㄮ㤰〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〳㐸⸳㈳‷〳㘷⸹㈰‵〳㤳⸸㐱‵㤲㤶⸸㜷″㠲㐷⸷㘶‵㜲㌵⸳㐶′㘲㐰⸶㜳‶㐲㔳⸰㠴‷㈲㐴⸵㔷‵〲㠳⸹〸ഹ 㜱㜹⸷㜸‱㔱㐷⸴㌱‴㌱㌲⸳㘴′〱㔵⸷㈶‶㤷㘰ㄮㄶ㔠ㄲ⸹㐲㈠㐷⸳㠹′㐷⸰㌸‸⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര ⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰‰⸰ര㌊㠰㌴㌮㜲㌠㠰㘷〮㜶㌠㐰㈷㐮㤹㈠㜹㈳㐮㠸㈠㜸㤷㐮㈸㈠㔷㠴㜮㐲㈠ㄶ〰㘮㘱㈠㌴㌸㈮ㄷ㈠㐲㤸㈮㜶㈠㌰ㄷㄮㄳ਍ㄠ㤷㘳㠮㠶ㄠ㜵㔰〮㤲ㄠ㈳㤳㌮㐱ㄠ㐰㔲㠮㐵㜠㤷⸹㠴‵ㄵ㜳㤮㈱㈠㐶⸵㘵㘠㤶㔮㘶〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮〠〮਍
```

Is this a type of chracter encoding? if so, can anyone recognise which one it is using?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer for you. Is the photometric file the IES?